# Error while trying to save the data to Hive tables from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

We have the following issue when we try to insert data into Hive table.

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 65.0 failed 4
>   times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 65.0 (TID 987,
>   tnblf585.test.sprint.com): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   45    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow.genericGet(rows.scala:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getAs(rows.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.isNullAt(rows.scala:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow.isNullAt(rows.scala:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$hive$execution$InsertIntoHiveTable$$writeToFile$1$1.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$hive$execution$InsertIntoHiveTable$$writeToFile$1$1.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:104)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$execution$InsertIntoHiveTable$$writeToFile$1(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$saveAsHiveFile$3.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$saveAsHiveFile$3.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:84)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:

Comment: it's not clear what and how you are trying to insert into hive table. an arrayoutofboundsexception thrown in the logs. it looks you data might be inconsistent. check your data.

Comment: You don't ask for anything specific, you don't provide source code, you don't provide sample data, you don't provide the target table structure, you don't mention Spark / Hive versions. And you really hope to get answers?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out that one of the column name in dataframe and hive table are not same , after the column name correction it has loaded correctly